# (Django) How to detect a request's behavior? User clicks a link or a button?

Tags: django, hyperlink, request

When user searching, the keywords and where the click from will be stored.

I use a hidden input named keyfrom to get where the click from.

```
<input type="hidden" name="keyfrom" value="web.index">
```

The url may be like this: `/?q='***'&keyfrom=web.index`

In middleware.py:

```
if request.GET.get('keyfrom', '')
    create a query record
```

I use django-pagination, page2's url may be like this: `/?q='***'&keyfrom=web.index&page=2`

This link will also cause middleware.py to create a record.

I don't want to store page2...n's data repeatedly.

I just want to store the data only when a user clicks the search button.

How to detect this behavior?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you could explicitly look for the `page` param in your middleware

```
if request.GET.get('keyfrom', '') and not request.GET.get('page'):
    create a query record
```